# While loop issues with reading the tokens

Tags: java, file, while-loop

I'm trying to read a list of tokens from a text file into separate variables by using a `while` loop.

Each line in the text file goes: `String`, `Double`, `Int`, `Int`, `Boolean`, and there are 11 lines, but I receive an `InputMisMatchException` for the `double` line after the `String` line.

The txt file reads as

1. AC 120.99 423 70 false
2. Toaster 18.99 101 30 true
3. Toaster 11.97 201 100 false
4. Yoyo 5.99 223 68 false 
   etc.

I've tried reading the file with `.hasNext` and `.hasNextLine`. When changing the `double` to `String` I get the error for the next `Int` and changing that to `String` again takes the error to the next `Int` but changing that does not move the exception further.

```
while (infp.hasNextLine() && count < LIMIT) {
    String Product_description = infp.next();
    double cost_per_item = infp.nextDouble(); //line 43
    int product_id = infp.nextInt();
    int quantity_at_hand = infp.nextInt();
    boolean domestic_origin = infp.hasNext();
    items[count] = new Item(Product_description, cost_per_item, 
                            product_id, quantity_at_hand, 
                            domestic_origin);
    count++;
}
```

It's supposed to read all the tokens into variables and just create separate objects for each line in the text file. But from the error I believe it is only reading the first `String` then throwing the exception for the `double`.

The exception on line 43:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
    java.util.InputMismatchException at 
    java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source) at
    java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source) at 
    java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source) at DB_Master.main(DB_Master.java:43)
```

Comment: `boolean domestic_origin = infp.hasNext();` is strange

Comment: You mention that there is an information for the `Boolean` but you don't read it, you just check if there is something to read with `hasNext`. So on the second line, when you get the `String` information, you actually gets the `Boolean` from the previous "item". And then you read for a `Double` but are still on the `String` line.

Comment: It might be a good idea to edit your question to include an actual example line or two from the file. In the second paragraph it's not completely clear (to me) whether each value is on a new line, with 11 groups of 5 lines, or whether all 5 values are in a single line; if it's the latter, it would be good to say what delimiters there are between each value.

Comment: which ide you are using?

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names are written in camelCase. That means they start with lowercase and contain no underscores.

Comment: @AxelH Thank You! That was the issue, It had completely passed over me, Thank you to everyone else with the great advise too!

Answer (score 0):

as you know nextDouble method is teruning a double value

```
double nextDouble()
Returns the next token as a long. If the next token is not a float or is out of range, InputMismatchException is thrown.
```

try give input in this format

like: 34,2 instead of 34.2

or try convert your Scanner with locale

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

**An instance of this class is capable of scanning numbers in the standard formats as well as in the formats of the scanner's locale. A scanner's initial locale is the value returned by the Locale.getDefault() method; it may be changed via the useLocale(java.util.Locale) method
The localized formats are defined in terms of the following parameters, which for a particular locale are taken from that locale's DecimalFormat object, df, and its and DecimalFormatSymbols object, dfs.**

for more ref see java [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#localized-numbers)

still not working try parsing by checking input type.

```
//************************************************************************

// MixedTypeInput

// This application demonstrates testing before reading to be

// sure to use the correct input method for the data.

//************************************************************************



import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MixedTypeInput

{

  public static void main(String[] args)

  {

    double number;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your gross income: ");

    if (in.hasNextInt())

    {

      number = (double)in.nextInt();

      System.out.println("You entered " + number);

    }

    else if (in.hasNextFloat())

    {

      number = (double)in.nextFloat();

      System.out.println("You entered " + number);

    }

    else if (in.hasNextDouble())

    {

      number = in.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("You entered " + number);

    }             

    else

      System.out.println("Token not an integer or a real value.");   

  }

}
```

Comment: You should mention that this code is a direct copy of some code at https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/ndale/Scanner.html.